# Password becomes invalid after I change my username in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, sudo, password

I changed my username by command `sudo usermod -l newUsername -d /home/newUsername -m oldUsername`. After that, the username does change. But when I use `sudo` command, the password typed in turns out to be incorrect. I am using ssh connection to that remote machine and I do not know the root password. Is there any way to deal with that without administrator's intervention?

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/sudoers` still contains your old username, and probably not you new one. This means you have given up your sudo rights, and getting help from an administrator is required.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sudo` authorisation was bound to the old user, as @Johan correctly says.

Depending on the configurations, your old user name is defined in `/etc/sudoers` or in most standard configurations, in the `sudo` group in the file `/etc/group`. It depends on the configuration your system administrador made.

Needless to say, you should have added the new user name in one of those two files next to the old name *before* changing the name of your user.

Now you have lost your `sudo` rights, and whilst there could be other technical solutions, in your case the best course of action is asking your system administrator.